# How to enable the wifi if we run the code on airplane mode (Android) using Appium

Tags: appium

I currently run the script on Airplane Mode and I want to enable my WIFI using appium.

Please let me know as to how to enable the wifi. I have used the following codes still no success.

```
ConnectionStateBuilder csb = new ConnectionStateBuilder();
csb.withWiFiEnabled().build();

AndroidDriver driver = (AndroidDriver) driver;
driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

toogleWifi will enable wifi

```
AndroidDriver driver = (AndroidDriver) driver; 
driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
driver.toggleWifi();
```

Comment: It does not work. I have used the above code but the wifi does not get enable. Also, toggleAirplaneMode only runs for version 6 and below.

Comment: The other way you can is to switch app and enable the wifi , but it is rigid especially if you are supporting multiple devices

Comment: Can you please add the code for that so that I can see it.